# Does the Fringe effect occur in capacitors in the interdigitated form?

Tags: electromagnetism, capacitance, field-theory

I am currently doing my undergrad dissertation on graphene supercapacitors. I have read that the fringe effect is a well established phenomenon on parallel plate capacitors, but does it also occur in capacitors in the interdigitated form? (For those that don't know what this is, its an in-plane device with the electrodes arranged much in the same way as putting your fingers on one hand in an alternating pattern with the fingers on the other.)

Comment: The "fringe effect" is simply the discrepancy between the electric field / potential between the plates of an ideal, infinite plate capacitor and a real, finite plate size one. Therefore, the answer is yes: however, I should think the aim would be to make separation between electrodes very small in comparison with the capacitor's other dimensions, so that one would foresee only small fringing effects - imagine an electric field across a very narrow corridor which wends around like the channel between the fingers, where the distance between bends is much greater than the corridor width. So ...

Comment: ...there will only be "fringing" at the bends, which account for only a small fraction of the corridor length